# Sumar Minutos a Date en Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy buscando la forma de sumar minutos a cualquier fecha Date.

Por ejemplo, dentro de mi código tengo el siguiente extracto.

```js
var actividad = '2019-09-13 06:45:00';
var fechaI2 = new Date(actividad);
minutoSumar = 60;

if (minutoSumar != 0) {
  fechaI2.setMinutes(fechaI2.getMinutes() + minutoSumar);

  console.log(fechaI2);
}
```

Cuando utilizo este extracto en vez de arrojar como hora las 07:45:00... Arroja como resultado 10:00:00 ya que no se porque me esta sumando el primer 7 de las horas mas el 4 de los minutos, sin embargo si yo colocase, 06:00:00 si da como resultado 07:00:00... No entiendo que sucede, ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba esta nueva function para sumar los minutos en **JavaScript**, se comporta como un metodo mas del `Date()`. La he probado y me ha dado buenos resultados sumando minutos al tiempo (igualmente puede sumar minutos en cualquier tiempo que asignes).

```js
// creacion de un metodo  addMins para la clase Date
Date.prototype.addMins = function(m) {     
   this.setTime(this.getTime() + (m*60*1000));  // minutos * seg * milisegundos
   return this;    
} 

// asignacion de valores de tiempo y suma de minutos en metodo addMins()
var actividad = '2019-09-13 06:45:00';
var fechaI2 = new Date (actividad);
minutoSumar = 45;

fechaI2.addMins(minutoSumar);
console.log(fechaI2);
```

Comment: Me retorna "2019-09-13T10:30:00.000Z" esta sumando 4 horas

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes en el código es el formato que le pasas al constructor de `Date()`, si en lugar de '2019-09-13 06:45:00' pones '2019-09-13T06:45:00Z' (**formato ISO**) funciona correctamente, al menos en mi caso, de cualquier manera ese formato utiliza el tiempo local, no universal:

```js
var actividad = '2019-09-13T06:45:00Z';
//var actividad = Date.UTC(2019, 8, 13, 6, 45, 0);// <-- idealmente
var fechaI2 = new Date(actividad);
minutoSumar = 60;

console.log(fechaI2);

if (minutoSumar != 0) {
    fechaI2.setMinutes(fechaI2.getMinutes() + minutoSumar);

    console.log(fechaI2);

}
```

Pasarle un string a `Date()` esta desaconsejado porque existen diferentes implementaciones de `Date.parse()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Timestamp_string

La mejor forma es en mi opinión usar [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/UTC) porque utiliza el tiempo universal (milisegundos desde Enero 1, 1970, 00:00:00) en lugar del tiempo local, ejemplo:

```js
var fecha = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 8, 13, 6, 45, 0));

 console.log(fecha);
```